# The connection is broken

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, npgsql

I'm connecting to a PostgreSQL database with the npgsql connector.

On average, with one out of every 50 000 queries, I get the following error. (This was while filling a dataset.)

This is the Exception Message:

```
The Connection is broken.
```

This is the Exception Inner Exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An  existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->    
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.IO.BufferedStream.FlushWrite()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlQuery.WriteToStream(Stream outputStream)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadyState.QueryEnum(NpgsqlConnector context, NpgsqlCommand command)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader(CommandBehavior cb)
```

Please let me know if I should rather post this in dba and if so I will repost.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about PostgreSQL but do you keep your connection open as short as possible? It's usually good practice to open the connection only when you need it and close it right after.

Comment: From your stack trace it seems you're using a pretty old version of Npgsql (2.x), try upgrading to 3.0.5. You should also examine the logs on PostgreSQL, it's likely you'll see an error message.

Comment: @Daniel Gee: Do you try upgrading to 3.0.5? Is it ok?

Comment: From what I can tell so far, it's an issue caused by the server. I had the logging level set too high on the server, so it was hard to tell what the issue was. I've now set the level lower and I will let you know what I discover.